# General::ivar "list" not a valid variable

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

So I have this data which relates concentrations to a rate

```
cAo = {0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.2}(*M*);
cBo = {0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05}(*M*);
r = {.0000246, .0000483, .0000501, .0001003, 0000239, .0000262}(*M/s*);
```

And I was also given an equation for the rate in the form of

```
k*(cAo^a)*(cBo^b)=r
```

So in order to find the constants a, b, and k, I used NonlinearModelFit

```
EQ1 = NonlinearModelFit[Data2, k*(cAo^a)*(cBo^b), {k, a, b}, {cAo, cBo}];
EQ1["BestFit"]
```

However for some reason I keep getting the error `General::ivar: "{0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.05,0.2} is not a valid variable."` which does not make any sense to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use `cAo` as a variable, as it has values assigned to it.  Maybe swapping the last two list will fix it. `Data2` is missing for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is something like this:

```
       NMinimize[Total[(k*(cAo^a)*(cBo^b)-r)^2],{a,b,k}]
```

Note I can't actually try this at this time.  I suspect you might need to add constraints, eg:

```
       NMinimize[{Total[(k*(cAo^a)*(cBo^b)-r)^2],{a>0,b>0,k>0}},{a,b,k}]
```